# Ubuntu server port 3306 is already listening at startup

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I try to start my docker which has a mysql image, it says the port 3306 is already in use. However, mysql is not even running...

Screenshot of what I've tried : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzxOn.png

My ubuntu server is simply installed from the windows store, pc was restarted, wsl too (I'm running wsl 2). I tried killing the pid 0, but that simply stopped my fluent terminal. I'm not sure what to do anymore since mysql is not running, mysqld neither, no containers are running, nothing...

If anyone knows, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command which should tell you what's reserving the port:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

You don't actually have to use 3306 for Mysql, you can modify it with the ports command, for example:

```
-p 4000:3306
```

will divert any traffic that is sent to port 4000 to port 3306.